# how to open file one time in for loop in a more elegant way

Tags: python

I am meeting some question that it would open the files multiple times in loop. So it would make the program slower. My code is shown below briefly.

```
def match_top_ans(annotation_ans):
    # this function is to match the annotation answers with the top answer 
      vocabulary 

    with open(top_ans_path, 'r') as f:
        top_ans = f.readlines()
    top_ans = [ans.strip() for ans in top_ans]
    valid_ans = [ans for ans in annotation_ans if ans in top_ans]
    return valid_ans
```

```
for idx, q in enumerate(questions):
    # deal with questions, e.g., get question id and match the corresponding 
      annotation 

    qu_id = qu['question_id']

    if labeled:
        with open(annotation_dir, 'r') as f:
            annotations = json.load(f)['annotations']
        annotation_ans = annotations[qu_id]['answers']
        valid_ans = match_top_ans(annotation_ans)
```

I can simply solve the question **by opening the files out of for loop** or **adding an extra booling variable like `open = False` to control it**.

```
with open(annotation_dir, 'r') as f:
    annotations = json.load(f)['annotations']

with open(top_ans_path, 'r') as f:
    top_ans = f.readlines()
top_ans = [ans.strip() for ans in top_ans]

for idx, q in enumerate(questions):
    # deal with questions, e.g., get question id and match the corresponding annotation 
    qu_id = qu['question_id']

    if labeled:

        annotation_ans = annotations[qu_id]['answers']
        valid_ans = match_top_ans(annotation_ans, top_ans)
```

but it seems that the code looks not elegant, because I want to separate the question part and answer part clearly, **is there any other more elegant way to solve this problem**?

Comment: what is your question exactly? please provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Tip: put with out of loop.

Comment: i want to discuss whether there is other ways to solve the question above without put with out of loop. I think it's not elegant

Comment: or setting a booling variable like ``open = False``

Comment: post the sample input and output how can someone understand what your code is doing? and also add some explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid opening and reading the whole file every time the function is being called and assuming that `top_ans_path` is constant, you could make `top_ans` and attribute of the function, which would make it behave exactly the same from an API perspective:

```
def match_top_ans(annotation_ans):
    if 'top_ans' not in match_top_ans.__dict__:
        with open(top_ans_path, 'r') as f:
            match_top_ans.top_ans = [line.strip() for line in f]

    valid_ans = [ans for ans in annotation_ans if ans in match_top_ans.top_ans]
    return valid_ans
```

this is akin to "static function variables" in languages inspired by C.

Having said that, if you care about performance, looking at `match_top_ans()` alone, there are already a few things that can improve runtime:

- First, use caching: this is now already performed through `top_ans` but keep in mind that there's no point in re-computing the same value over and over (for example, your `top_ans = [ans.strip() ...`) if they never change.
- Second, every assignment ("`=`") is going to re-write every item of the list to memory, changing it slightly so try to avoid assignments as much as possible. I got rid of the `readlines()` assignement by using `f` directly as an iterator over the lines of the file. Iterators are your friends here because they will combine all operations into one and read-write each item once.
- Third, use appropriate data types! Python only provides a few elementary data structures; use them wisely! Your `top_ans` should really be a `set` instead of a `list`: does it makes sense to have the same answer more than once or does the order of the answers in `top_ans` matter? If not, a `set` is a better alternative because its implementation of `in` is **much** faster for large numbers of answers as, unlike `list`'s `in`, it doesn't have to check every single item it holds.
- Fourth, once you use the appropriate data types, use the appropriate operations: what you're computing, in set theory terminology, is the intersection between `top_ans` and `annotation_ans` (which you call `valid_ans`): using sets, you can obtain that through `intersection` or `&` which will be more efficient than your own loop ("`for ans in annotation_ans if ...`).

Putting it all together, a more efficient `match_top_ans` would look like:

```
def match_top_ans(annotation_ans):
    if 'top_ans' not in match_top_ans.__dict__:
        with open(TOP_ANS_PATH) as f:
            match_top_ans.top_ans = {line.strip() for line in f}

    return match_top_ans.top_ans & set(annotation_ans)
```

Comment: It took me a while to watch your answer. The ``top_ans`` is read on a txt file and I already  processed it so it would not shown the repeated answers again. In this situation is there still faster to use ``set`` ?

Comment: Yes because `in` can know in a few operations if a "thing" is in a set or not (see [hash functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)) while it needs to check against every single item of a list one-by-one.

Comment: Note that this is particularly true when you have many items, if you only have a few, you will probably not see any benefit. Also, I used `set(annotation_ans)` here to point to the fact that those could also be defined as a `set` (but they are defined outside of `match_top_ans`); an in-between solution would be to keep the set for `top_ans` but return the list/set comprehension you were initially using: this will use the "fast" `in` without spending the effort of converting `annotation_ans` to as set itself.

Comment: This answer benefits me a lot !! Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: by the way, the ``__dict__`` can see the static function variables. do you know is there any way to see the local variable in function ?